# Pytest teardown of postgresql database in Flask is happening before tests are done

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, pytest

The tests below ran fine when I was using SQLite as the test database. However, the application now requires Postgresql, which is "causing" the tests to hang. While running, when I inspect via `select * from pg_stat_activity`, the teardown or db.drop_all() process is trying to drop tables (some are dropped) while the second query in `test_login_logout` is still running.

If I remove `db.drop_all()` the tests run fine but obviously the database is not wiped-out. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def test_client():
    app = create_app('testing')
    with app.test_client() as testing_client:
            with app.app_context():
                yield testing_client


@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def init_database(test_client):

    db.create_all()

    admin_role = Role(name='admin')
    db.session.add(admin_role)

    user = User(username='testuser', password='password', role=admin_role)
    db.session.add(user)

    db.session.commit()

    yield

    db.drop_all()


class TestPublic:

    def test_login_logout(self, test_client, init_database):
        response = test_client.post('/login', data=dict(
            username='testuser', password='password'), follow_redirects=True)
        assert response.status_code == 200
        assert b"Login successful." in response.data

        response = test_client.post('/login', data=dict(
            username='x', password='x'), follow_redirects=True)
        assert response.status_code == 200
        assert b"Invalid username or password." in response.data

        response = test_client.get('/logout', follow_redirects=True)
        assert response.status_code == 200
        assert b"You have been logged out." in response.data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the query status in postgresql said it was "idle_in_transaction" and after a few more searches [this article](https://xvrdm.github.io/2017/07/03/testing-flask-sqlalchemy-database-with-pytest/) indicated adding `db.session.remove()` after the yield would help with the locking issue. It works now! For reference:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def init_database(test_client):

    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()

    admin_role = Role(name='admin')
    db.session.add(admin_role)

    user = User(username='testuser', password='password', role=admin_role)
    db.session.add(user)

    db.session.commit()

    yield

    db.session.remove()
    db.drop_all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `db.drop_all()` statement from there and add this function, it's automatically called after all the tests finish:

```
def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    """ whole test run finishes. """
    db.drop_all()
```

Source: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_sessionfinish